# Javascript ip address comparison

Tags: javascript, networking, ip-address

In Python, I use the [netaddr](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to make it easy to do ip address comparison and sort operations. For instance:

```
IPAddress('1.2.3.4') < IPAddress('3.4.5.6')
IPAddress('1.2.3.4') is in IPNetwork('1.0.0.0/8')
```

Now I need to do the same in Javascript, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel..

I'm coming up short on finding a node package that makes it easy to do similar comparisons. I've found some (like [netmask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/netmask)) that are pretty solid but are IPv4 only. I need to support both IPv4 AND IPv6 comparisons.

So, my requirements are:

- Node Package
- Supports parsing IPv4 AND IPv6 CIDRs and IP Addresses
- Supports "compare" and "contains" operations
- Well-tested

Comment: You didn't look very far lol.. https://www.npmjs.com/package/netaddr

Comment: Neither did you :-) -- "Limitations -- 
Currently only IPv4 is supported, though there are plans to add IPv6 support. This is complicated by the fact JavaScript does not support 64-bit integers, let alone 128-bit integers."

Comment: I had previously looked at the node implementation of netaddr, but IPv6 isn't supported...

Comment: Geezz, that's open source for ya

Answer (score 0):

I was a little surprised that after 4 years this didn't have a decent answer. I had a use for one, and between lodash and ipaddr.js, the world was so close that I decided to complete a solution. It is 3.5-parts & uses two libraries. That may seem heavy, but you may already have lodash, and if you need to sort IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, you probably could already benefit from `ipaddr.js`.

(I was a little surprised that `ipaddr.js` didn't have something for this yet. If people like this and nobody shares a better solution, I'd be willing to submit this as an enhancement to the module)

**TL/DR:**

1. Use npm `ipaddr.js` to parse your IP addresses; yields comparable parts (`xtets`)
2. Use `lodash.sortBy` for compact multi-dimensional sort

   1. If comparing both inet4 and inet6 addrs, use the `family` property as the first `iteratee`
   2. Generate an array of `iteratees` to compare successive elements of the `octets` or `parts` arrays that `ipaddr.js` produces.

**Implementation**

```js
// support fns/vars
const iteratees = [];
const xtet = n => (addr => (addr.octets || addr.parts)[n]); 
for(let i=0; i<8; i++) iteratees.push(xtet(i));
// the actual IP address sort function
const sortAddrs = (addrs) => _.sortBy(addrs, [ 'family', ...iteratees ]);

// Example usage (100 < 2 in string sort)
const addrs = ['fed0:100::1', '10.100.0.1', 'fed0:2::1', '10.2.0.1'];
const parsed = addrs.map((a) => ipaddr.parse(a));
const sorted = sortAddrs(parsed);
console.log(sorted.map(a => a.toString()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ipaddr.js/2.1.0/ipaddr.min.js"></script>
```

**Discussion**

[ipaddr.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipaddr.js?activeTab=code) is a powerful IP address inspection and manipulation library. Step one is to parse addresses. The resulting objects have either an `octets` (v4) or `parts` (v6) property, which is simply an integer representation of each `xtet`, highest-order first. (I may have just coined `xtet`, I'm not sure).

[lodash.sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy) simplifies complex sorting by letting you focus directly on each iteration of the sort comparison. It takes a collection, and a list of "iteratees." Successive iteratees will only be called if two objects continue to to be equal on prior iteratees.

I'm sorting on family first, b/c comparing v4 addresses to v6 addresses is meaningless (without additional context that would dictate how they should sort). Thus, `'family'` is the first "iteratee".

Next, we give `sortBy` an array of iteratees that compare successive xtets. My code here manufactures an array of 8 tiny functions that each return the nth element of either `octets` or `parts`. Those are integers that are directly comparable for sorting purposes.

There may be a tighter way to produce that array, but I couldn't think of one. Within the family, comparing one xtet to another is as correct as converting the addresses to a single huge integer.

Note: It does not appear to crash if you leave out the `family` iteratee. However I wouldn't consider the results meaningful; The first octet of a v4 address will almost always be less than the first hextet of a v6 address, except for corner cases like loopbacks.